# This page contains the following errors: creates html instead of XML

Tags: php, xml, pdo

Now i get this error.

**This page contains the following errors:
error on line 3 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.**

Somehow the output is rending my XML file as an HTML.
I have double and tripled checked the Attributes, and they are correct... And i cant seem to find the error... any friends with clues ?

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);

    class Areas{
    private $link; 
    public function __construct(){
    $this->link = new Connection();
    $this->link = $this->link->dbConnect();
}

  function fetch_area() {
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");  
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

        while($row = $query->fetch()) {  
          $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
          $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
          $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
          $newnode->setAttribute("adress", $row['adress']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
        } 
   }
  }
$area = new Areas();
$area_info = $area->fetch_area(); 
echo $dom->saveXML();
```

Comment: Do you set the headers to tell the browser your code is outputing XML?

Comment: header("Content-type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");

Comment: @andrewsi Yes, its there. 
 header("Content-type: text/xml");

Comment: @Dymond - you should put that at the top of the file, so it's the first thing that's output.

Comment: @andrewsi yes, but i have tried to put it everywhere. But still no luck.

Comment: @Dymond - Could you try putting it at the top of the file, and then running the PHP from the command line? Maybe there's something in there generating an error that's being rendered as HTML?

Comment: I don't see the dbConnect() function defined. Could connecting be the problem?

Comment: @kevin the connection is fine, its included. and some other functions are working fine with the dbConnect();

Comment: @andrewsi I have it in the top now. 
how do you mean run it from the command line ?

in the prompt ?

Comment: @Dymond - that's right. Try `php filename.php` and see what it outputs.

Comment: @andrewsi im hassling some with the run, will be back when I get it.
But as Ray C told answers, the global variables solved the problem.. but I don't really get why.

Comment: @Dymond - it's a scope issue. You have to pass in variables you want to use in a function, or declare them as globals. If you don't, PHP will generate an error message, which is presumably what is being interpreted as HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fast fixing, you should add following code at first of the `fetch_area()` function.

```
global $dom, $node, $parnode;
```

So that you function will look like this:

```
function fetch_area() {
    global $dom, $node, $parnode;
    $query = $this->link->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");  
    $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    header("Content-type: text/xml");

        while($row = $query->fetch()) {  
          $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
          $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
          $newnode->setAttribute("name",$row['name']);
          $newnode->setAttribute("adress", $row['adress']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);  
          $newnode->setAttribute("type", $row['type']);
        } 
   }
```

Also for better coding, you d better take out

```
header("Content-type: text/xml");
```

Just before `echo $dom->saveXML();` is good position.

Comment: Because inside the function, it only refers local scope variable. you did not define any variable like $dom in function, $dom considered null inside of function. It is all about variable scope, so please refer http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: I get that, but i though since i was using a class i would skip the global var.. but hey. it works like a charm now :)

Comment: Personally, I think you d better not use global. You d better passing those as function parameter, or class variable. :-)

Comment: No really I don't like to use global variables, but since I know now what was the problem, its easier to do it better. Im really new on class programming :)

Comment: I totally agree on Ray's comment. There's absolutely no reason to use globals here.